# grep command-line search string in all .zip in folder and extract it. in windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line, grep, zip

am new to grep so please take it easy thanks.
here is what i have,i have a folder with 1000 .zip files small sizes and i want to search all them using a string and if it matches then extract only the matched string to another folder.

```
grep "u74" *.zip
```

ok the code above i i placed 1 zip file in grep folder and searched for u74 and it matches.

how do i make a search.bat and leave all zip in their original folder rather then moving them to grep folder.
my grep installation folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin

here are some codes i found but its not working

```
for i in *.zip; do 
    echo "scanning $i";
grep -oP "u74" <(unzip -l "$i") && echo "Found in $i" || echo "Not Found in $i"; 
pause
```

this is exactly what  i want but its not working
lastly i want to create a folder in same zip path and found and move all found files their.

Comment: The script you found is clearly shell script, not BATCH script. You can install cygwin and do it from there, it'll be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

the way you propose to use grep in your question means that it would find the string "u74" in the *compressed* data.

The Unix/Linux script you found (as observed by David, it won't run on Win) solves this problem by unzipping every zip in a subprocess, that is the (unzip -l ...) part.

Short of installing cygwin or python for Windows, what you can do is unpack all zips into a location like D:\My_Data and then either

```
grep "u74" D:\My_Data\*.*
```

or

you cd into D:\My_Data and from there you run

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep "u74" *.*
```